# Why doesn't KivyMD's toolbar navigation drawer work with datatables?

Tags: datatable, kivy, navigation-drawer, toolbar, kivymd

This code should produce a window that has a datatable in the main area, and a top navigation bar with a
Navigation menu. It works as intended for a number of other uses. Buttons, text fields, dialogue boxes, etc. have no problem, the navigation menu pops out just as it is supposed to. But the second I add the table widget the toolbar menu no longer functions.

I've tried every combination that I can think of to no avail.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp


mgr = """
Screen:            
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: Landing_Manager
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'test'
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        elevation:9
                    ScreenManager: 
                        id: Screen_Manager
                        NewScreen:
                            id: New_Screen
                            name: 'NewScreen'
                            manager: Screen_Manager
                            
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        id: container
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Item 1'
                            on_press: 
                                nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Item 2'
                            on_press: 
                                nav_drawer.set_state("close")
<NewScreen>
                                
"""
class NewScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        self.rows = 3
        self.rowInfo = [('','item 1', 'info 1a', 'info1b'), 
                         ('','item 2', 'info 2a', 'info2b'),
                         ('','item 3', 'info 3a', 'info3b')]
        self.colHeaders = [('check col',dp(30)),
                           ("data col 1",dp(40)),
                           ("data col 2",dp(50)),
                            ("data col 3", dp(20))]  

        
        table = MDDataTable(column_data = self.colHeaders,
                            check = True,
                            rows_num = self.rows,
                            row_data = self.rowInfo)
    
        self.add_widget(table)
        
class LookBusyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        self.screen = ScreenManager()
        self.app = Builder.load_string(mgr)
        self.screen.add_widget(NewScreen(name = 'NewScreen'))
        
        return self.app
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = LookBusyApp()
    app.run()
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So I tracked down the issue and have a fix. I don't know if it is the best fix but it seems to work.
In kivymd.uix.datatables the MDDataTable class was inheriting from BaseDialog, which didn't seem to like working with the screenmanager, I changed the inheriting to Screen and it works.

original:

```
from kivymd.uix.dialog import BaseDialog
.
.
.
class MDDataTable(BaseDialog):
```

updated:

```
from kivymd.uix.dialog import Screen
.
.
.
class MDDataTable(Screen):
```

Additionally, from the builder-> MDDataTable ->canvas these 2 lines needs to be removed:

```
Color:
    rgba: root.theme_cls.bg_normal
```